# The code doesn't work (Uncaught ReferenceError: $ajaxUtils is not defined))

Tags: javascript, ajax

I can't understand what the error is
(Uncaught ReferenceError: $ajaxUtils is not defined)

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    showLoading("#main-content");
    $ajaxUtils.sendGetRequest(
        homeHtml,
        function (responseText) {
            document.querySelector("#main-content").innerHTML = responseText;
        },
    false);
});
```

Comment: Do you have a script in page that you think defines `$ajaxUtils`?

Comment: Yes, <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: `$ajaxUtils` is not part of jQuery.js

Answer (score 0):

$ajaxUtils is not part of jQuery.js

So make a new ajax-utils.js file and inside that use this code :

```
(function(global) {
// Set up a namespace for our utility
var ajaxUtils = {};


// Returns an HTTP request object
function getRequestObject() {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    return (new XMLHttpRequest());
  } 
  else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    // For very old IE browsers (optional)
    return (new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"));
  } 
  else {
    global.alert("Ajax is not supported!");
    return(null); 
  }
}


// Makes an Ajax GET request to 'requestUrl'
ajaxUtils.sendGetRequest = 
  function(requestUrl, responseHandler, isJsonResponse) {
    var request = getRequestObject();
    request.onreadystatechange = 
      function() { 
        handleResponse(request, 
                       responseHandler,
                       isJsonResponse); 
      };
    request.open("GET", requestUrl, true);
    request.send(null); // for POST only
  };


// Only calls user provided 'responseHandler'
// function if response is ready
// and not an error
function handleResponse(request,
                        responseHandler,
                        isJsonResponse) {
  if ((request.readyState == 4) &&
     (request.status == 200)) {

    // Default to isJsonResponse = true
    if (isJsonResponse == undefined) {
      isJsonResponse = true;
    }

    if (isJsonResponse) {
      responseHandler(JSON.parse(request.responseText));
    }
    else {
      responseHandler(request.responseText);
    }
  }
}


// Expose utility to the global object
global.$ajaxUtils = ajaxUtils;


})(window);
```

Make sure to link ajax-query.js to index.html page :)